# How to right align images for responsive email with empty space to the left

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design, html-email

I'm aiming to right align 4 social icons in the header of an email. Mock up and code below. The main issue I've run into is that there is only empty space to the left side of the icons. An empty td with a width pushes the set of images outside of the viewable area at small screen sizes.

Ideally the icons would be right:0; or floated to the right. Although we know float is to be avoided in email.

Mock up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O1j1.png

The code below stacks the social icons directly beneath the logo on the left side of the table.

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td>

        <!-- HEADER CONTENT -->
        <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
            <tr>
                <td align="left" style="display:inline-block">
                    <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" style="display:block; padding-top:32px; font:300 16px/24px Arial, sans-serif; color:#000;" width="286"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="display:inline-block; padding-top:4px;  padding-bottom:14px;">
                    <a href="#" style="display:inline-block; text-decoration:none; padding-right:10px;"><img src="social-fb.png" alt="FB" width="18" /></a>
                    <a href="#" style="display:inline-block; text-decoration:none; padding-right:10px;"><img src="social-blog.png" alt="blog" width="18" /></a>
                    <a href="#" style="display:inline-block; text-decoration:none; padding-right:10px;"><img src="social-twitter.png" alt="twitter" width="18" /></a>
                    <a href="#" style="display:inline-block; text-decoration:none;"><img src="social-linkedIn.png" alt="linkedIn" width="18" /></a>
                </td>  
            </tr>
        </table>


    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: width="600" - responsive? http://jsfiddle.net/b56Lfvck/

Comment: `<td style="text-align: right; padding-top:4px;  padding-bottom:14px;">`?

Answer (score 2):

You can just align the `<td>` that contains the social buttons to the right.

This is supported in most email clients including a lot of mobile clients.  I ran this code through Email On Acid and it is supported in all major desktop clients except Thunderbird and all mobile clients except the Android and iOS Gmail app.

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td><!-- HEADER CONTENT -->

      <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" style="display:inline-block"><img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" style="display:block; padding-top:32px; font:300 16px/24px Arial, sans-serif; color:#000;" width="286"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right" style="display:inline-block; padding-top:4px;  padding-bottom:14px;"><a href="#" style="display:inline-block; text-decoration:none; padding-right:10px;"><img src="social-fb.png" alt="FB" width="18" /></a> <a href="#" style="display:inline-block; text-decoration:none; padding-right:10px;"><img src="social-blog.png" alt="blog" width="18" /></a> <a href="#" style="display:inline-block; text-decoration:none; padding-right:10px;"><img src="social-twitter.png" alt="twitter" width="18" /></a> <a href="#" style="display:inline-block; text-decoration:none;"><img src="social-linkedIn.png" alt="linkedIn" width="18" /></a></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you wrapping the table in an html and body tag? The code you've posted works without, but inside these tags I get the same result as I did previously.

Comment: I typically avoid using the body tag because some email clients strip it and put there own body tag with attributes or convert it to a div tag such as Gmail.